# How to remove all items except the first item from dropdownlist in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to clear drpAddressTypes dropdown values except the first item and bind again that dropdownlist.

```
drpAddressTypes.Items.Clear();
var lstAddressTypes = repository.GetAddressTypes(userId);
if (lstAddressTypes != null)
{
  foreach (var item in lstAddressTypes)
   {
     var addressType = new ListItem(item, item);
     drpAddressType.Items.Add(addressType);
   }
}
```

When I am using  ***drpAddressTypes.Items.Clear();*** it is clearing all items. 
How can I clear all items except the first item.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: you are asking how to delete all elements from a list except the fist one

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was looking to delete all items from the dropdown list except the first item.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could retrive the firstitem and then clear the list and add the item again.

```
var firstitem = drpAddressType.Items[0];

drpAddressType.Items.Clear();
drpAddressType.Items.Add(firstitem);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Items.RemoveRange(1, items.Count-1)`..

Answer (score 4):

You can just remember the first item, clear everything and then put that remembered item back.

```
ListItem first = drpAddressTypes.Items[0];
drpAddressTypes.Items.Clear();
drpAddressTypes.Items.Add(first);
```

Answer (score 1):

drpAddressTypes.Items.RemoveRange(1, drpAddressTypes.Count - 1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
Items.RemoveRange(drpAddressTypes.Items.Skip(1))
```